# Spring Data not working for Gradle projects under Eclipse without @Param annotations for method parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, gradle, spring-data-jpa

So I'm using Gradle, Eclipse, Java 11, Spring Boot with some Spring Data JPA repositories.
In Eclipse, I've tested with 3 different JDK libraries configured in the build path and in the execution: OpenJDK, OracleJDK and GraalVM.
I get the same error every time:
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Either use @Param on all parameters except Pageable and Sort typed once, or none at all!`
Because of a line like:

```java
@Query("select e from Entity e where e.value = :value")
Optional<Entity> findByValue(String value);
```

Guaranteed to work would be to add `@Param("value")` for the parameter, but I don't want to do that because this project has a lot of repositories.
If I run this under the command line `./gradlew bootRun` where I set one of the JDKs, this error does not occur.

If I try to reproduce this under a new project, but under Maven where I set the properties for java and maven for Java 11, then it works just fine under Eclipse.

The Gradle project works fine under a IntelliJ IDEA.

Can someone please help in explaining why this is happening? Does Eclipse bode well with Maven but not with Gradle? I can't fine an explanation.

Comment: Does [running Eclipse with Java 11](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) fix your issue?

Comment: @howlger thanks for the response, I've ran Eclipse under all java versions (8, 11, 17) but it was not an issue. Anyway, I've figured it out and I'm preparing a detailed response for this so it can help anyone who has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a compiler argument.

Seems that when the code is compiled, depending on the project, it will run with or without the `-parameters` argument to the `javac` command. When you run `javac --help`, the following line explains:

```
...
  -parameters
        Generate metadata for reflection on method parameters
...
```

This parameter is vital if you don't want to use `@Param("value")` in the repository method parameter, because this helps Spring Data determine the name of the parameter and assign it to `:value`.

In Eclipse(as of 2022-06), for your specific project, go to project **`Properties > Java Compiler`** and check **`"Store information about method parameters(usable via reflection)"`** and the project will work without "@Param" annotations in the repository method parameters:
[image]

I still find it strange why on Maven projects this is activated but not on Gradle projects.

These answers helped me:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38198699/4632181
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44075684/4632181

For IntelliJ IDEA, this might be a useful answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24652186/4632181